# How can I put a degree symbol (º) on an OpenCv Video?

Tags: python, opencv, plot, computer-vision, symbols

I made a program which make a HUD over a video, getting info from sensors and plotting the results on the video frames, refreshing every frame, and for representing degrees (inclination) I need to plot a degree symbol, but what I get it's 2 symbols ("??") in the video show. I search through this site and others too. I can't do it!!!! please, I don't know what to do, it's just that little thing that I can't do it.

This is the beginning of my program:

```
import cv2
from random import *
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(r"e:\Usuario\Desktop\HUD\Videos\Car.mp4")
out = cv2.VideoWriter('HUD.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','P','4','2'), 25, (1280, 720))
```

and this is the line that i need put the symbol

```
cv2.putText(frame, (str(data[3]) + "º"), (275,690),font,0.7,(255,255,255),1)
```

data it's a variable who save the values from a function, everything works perfectly, it just that symbol!!!! y try many things and no one can help me.

in this lines show the video just for check, also my program write it in a directory...

```
out.write(frame)
cv2.imshow("Testing", frame)
```

I got python 3.5.3 and windows 10 if that information it's useful for you. And i repeat, it's not the program, it just the way that i'm trying to plot the degree symbol, thats the only problem here, thanks!!!

Comment: Have you tried the unicode  `u'\u00b0'`?

Comment: how? just like a string? yeah, i try some of that codes

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. But you need to install pillow `pip install pillow`.

```
import cv2
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((200,400,3),np.uint8)
b,g,r,a = 0,255,0,0

fontpath = "./simsun.ttc" # the font that has this "º" symbol
font = ImageFont.truetype(fontpath, 32)
img_pil = Image.fromarray(img)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_pil)

draw.text((50, 80),  "100 º", font = font, fill = (b, g, r, a))

img = np.array(img_pil)

cv2.imshow("img", img)    

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: and if you want a different font? the answer at present is rather specific.

Comment: I guess you just need to change the file path to the font that you want

Comment: ...and you further have to hope that those other font has the needed char in there.